# How to identify right click disabled javascript modal dialog box elements in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

In my application clicking a button triggers an `onclick` method which returns a modal dialog box.

I am trying to pass control over to the box and proceed. But right click is disabled in it and so not able to identify any of the elements in it.

F12/Firebug shows only parent window contents.
Java/Selenium WebDriver POM framework

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Resh

Comment: what do you mean by model dialog box, is it windows ? like printer and download, is so it's not HTML and so you can't see the code or automate it.

Comment: Its not windows dialog box